# Application-Controlled Session Stickiness: enable stickiness on all cookies?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cookies, configuration, server, load-balancing

I have my production servers running behind a load balancer on AWS (they scale up based on an AMI). Some websites have cookies - for example, a restaurant with multiple locations, and each location is set in a cookie.

I noticed that a cookie wasn't being saved across multiple servers, so I remedied this by going into `Load Balancers -> Port Configuration`, clicking `Enable Application Generated Cookie Stickiness`, and inserting the name of the cookie.

As far as I know, this only allows one cookie name, and I have many - Google Analytics, for example. (Perhaps they can be comma separated, I haven't checked yet.)

My port configuration now looks like this:

```
80 (HTTP) forwarding to 80 (HTTP)
Stickiness: AppCookieStickinessPolicy, cookieName='MY_COOKIE'
```

**I was wondering if there was any way to allow ANY app generated cookie to be recognized, instead of having to name them individually.**

Any input greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: "I noticed that a cookie wasn't being saved across multiple servers" Can you elaborate what you mean by that? A cookie is stored in a browser, by domain. Do you mean that you want a cookie to be shared across domains?

Comment: So, I have a location selector - let's say a restaurant with 5 locations. Let's say you choose "Chicago" then click on menu. The first time it loads the Chicago menu page. If you refresh, it will load the Las Vegas menu page. If you refresh again, it will load the Chicago menu page. I have the page behind a load balancer that is round robin-ing between two servers. Obviously somehow it's not accepting the cookies on one server, and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you sure that isn't some sort of caching issue? Are you using a CDN? I would definitely debug that before assuming it is the cookie. Also, you can use developer tools in Firefox or Chrome to see what cookie was sent for each request, which would tell you if the cookie is being sent every time.

Comment: Yeah, the cookie is loading fine, but the correct page isn't being loaded 50% of the time. It defaults to one location that we have as the "else" location. Also, on my dev server which is running behind one load balancer, there is no issue, which is why I immediately jumped to the dual server thing. Tried clearing history, cookies, and using a different browser, but no avail.

Comment: Do you actually have logins and persistent sessions on these sites? You should only set session stickiness to a cookie that is going to have a unique value for each user. If you set it to some cookie that stores the user's selected location, then it will treat every user with that selection as the same user. That's why people generally use a session ID. Honestly this doesn't sound like your issue though if it was broke when you were using the default load balancer cookie. That should have worked fine. You'll need to debug this some on the server side.

Comment: Watch your logs on each server to determine if requests from one user are being sent to more than one server. Are you using static variables to store session information? That would definitely cause this issue, if 2 or more users are overwriting each other's session data.

Comment: Thanks, still working on the issue...we'll see what happens. I realized I'm also having issues with contact forms going through and AJAX. Server migration is a headache.

Comment: @mbaird Thanks for your help on this issue. I was able to solve it by adding a `?=location` to all my URLs based on the cookie. Probably not the best fix, but it worked, so that's that for now.

Comment: If adding a query parameter fixed it, then it sounds like some sort of page caching issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the use and purpose of session stickiness.

If you don't have a shared session store - i.e. memcached, redis, or something that is available to ALL instances in your pool, then you're probably using a session mechanism that involves local storage - saving them on a local file system is a common mechanism for php, while IIS will usually have a local session store.

If you're using a local session store, then you need to make sure that all subsequent request come back to the node that has the session stored - because if it doesn't, then whatever information your application has saved in session is no longer available.

To do this, you have two choices:  allow the ELB to set and manage the session affinity cookie, or have it do it based on the session cookie you set.  Note that in both cases, the ELB will create a new cookie with the name AWSELB and a value that allows it to map the request to the instance that original created it - but if you tie it to the session cookie set when the ELB only generates the AWSELB cookie when it sees a new session cookie.

It sounds like the application problem could be because you're pulling the location from session, not from the cookie, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thank you for your informative response! I'm definitely misunderstanding the purpose of session stickiness, as it's all new to me.